# Java - switch case, Multiple cases call the same function

Tags: java, switch-statement

Since I have multiple `String` cases which should be handled the same way, I tried:

```
switch(str) {
// compiler error
case "apple", "orange", "pieapple":
  handleFruit();
  break;
}
```

But I get a compiler error.

Should I have to, in Java, call the same function case by case:

```
switch(str) {
  case "apple":
      handleFruit();
       break;
  // repeat above thing for each fruit
  ...
}
```

Is there no simpler style?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to use `case` keyword for each String like this :

```
switch (str) {
    //which mean if String equals to
    case "apple":      // apple
    case "orange":     // or orange
    case "pieapple":   // or pieapple
        handleFruit();
        break;
}
```

---

**Edit 02/05/2019**

### Java 12

From Java 12 there are a new syntax of switch case proposed, so to solve this issue, here is the way:

```
switch (str) {
    case "apple", "orange", "pieapple" -> handleFruit();
}
```

Now, you can just make the choices separated by comma, the an arrow `->` then the action you want to do.

Another syntax also is :

consider that each case return a value, and you want to set values in a variable, lets suppose that `handleFruit()` return a `String` the old syntax should be :

```
String result;  //  <-------------------------- declare 
switch (str) {
    //which mean if String equals to
    case "apple":      // apple
    case "orange":     // or orange
    case "pieapple":   // or pieapple
        result = handleFruit();  //      <----- then assign
        break;
}
```

now with Java 12, you can make it like this :

```
String result = switch (str) { //  <----------- declare and assign in one shot
    case "apple", "orange", "pieapple" -> handleFruit();
}
```

Nice syntax

Comment: I believe the new switch statement syntax is available in Java 14, not 12. More info here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/language/switch-expressions.html

Comment: @ArielMirra thank you for the info, I'm not sure about this information, take a look to this https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/language/switch-expressions.html or https://mkyong.com/java/java-12-switch-expressions/

Answer (score 6):

Java supports [fall-through when](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) you have no `break`:

```
case "apple":
case "orange":
case "pieapple":
    handleFruit();
    break;
```

Answer (score 4):

You got error because you used comma between case queries.
To define multiple cases, you have to use semi colon
so like this.

```
switch (str) {
case "orange": case "pineapple": case "apple":
     handleFruit();
     break;
}
```