# Unable to understand how it works case MONDAY : FRIDAY:

Tags: java, switch-statement

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import static java.time.DayOfWeek.*;
public class Test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        var today=LocalDate.now().with(WEDNESDAY).getDayOfWeek();
        switch(today)
        {
            case SUNDAY:
            case SATURDAY:
                System.out.println("Enjoy");
                break;
            case MONDAY : FRIDAY:
                System.out.println("Boaring");
            default:
                System.out.println("QuestionMark");
        }       
    }
}
```

How it is working. any one can you please help. Especially this line eating my mind :

```
case MONDAY : FRIDAY:
```

Comment: You should try running this for all days of the week (e.g. `for (var day : DayOfWeek.values())`), and see if it does what you think it would.

Comment: @AndyTurner This seems to be some sort of trick question posed to the OP.

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a nasty case of syntax abuse. In this particular case, `case MONDAY:` does what I think you expect.

However, the `FRIDAY:` has *nothing at all* to do with the switch block. It's a [Java label](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.7) attached to the following `println` statement, and since it's never referred to, it simply has no meaning other than to be seriously confusing.

Note: Never use labels. There are much clearer ways to express your ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I think that chrylis has already nicely explained how your code works. As a little more background: Programming languages exist that accept a range of values as case label in a switch-like statement. However, in Java and other languages with C-like `switch` statements you need to specify each case individually, like this:

```
    case MONDAY:
    case TUESDAY:
    case WEDNESDAY:
    case THURSDAY:
    case FRIDAY:
        System.out.println("Boaring");
        break;
```

You were also missing the `break` statement that I think was intended after printing `Boaring` (or the case would “fall through” to the next case and additionally print `QuestionMark`).

Java 12 has some improvements of the `switch` statement syntax. See for example the edit in [this answer by YCF_L](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48233503/5772882).